# how can i activate "page layout" option in page tab in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: page-layout, branding

I just downloaded a package to brand my portal, which is SharePoint 2013. I do the exact steps of the document and guide, but for the last step, to select proper page layout, this option is not active and the UI doesn't change for all the pages...can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On a teamsite for instance - do the following:

Activate the following features:

- Site Collection Features - SharePoint Server Publishing
- Site Features - SharePoint Server Publishing

~ Navigate to the page library (Pages) ~ Create a new page ~ Set the new page as the welcome page of your site ~ Delete the SitePages library

From now on, you will fully use the publishing features (page layouts).

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` Site Collection Feature and after that you can activate the `SharePoint Server Publishing` site (web) feature.

This will create the necessary libraries (Pages library) inside the current web and you should be able to select a page layouts (for pages residing inside the pages library).

I think you will have to reset the Welcome Page after the activation to a page inside the pages library.